# Inserir Eventos no banco de dados pelo FullCalendar

Tags: php, javascript, fullcalendar

Gostaria de saber se tem alguma maneira de eu inserir algum evento no banco de dados pelo `FullCalendar`,

Eu peguei a versão atual e vi que tem uma função que ele aparece um prompt para eu digitar o titulo do evento, mas esta somente em js então se eu atualizo a página ele não deixa o evento registrado.

Como posso fazer isso?
Segue o código abaixo

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var currentLangCode = 'pt-br';

        // build the language selector's options
        $.each($.fullCalendar.langs, function(langCode) {
            $('#lang-selector').append(
                $('<option/>')
                    .attr('value', langCode)
                    .prop('selected', langCode == currentLangCode)
                    .text(langCode)
            );
        });

        // rerender the calendar when the selected option changes
        $('#lang-selector').on('change', function() {
            if (this.value) {
                currentLangCode = this.value;
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy');
                renderCalendar();
            }
        });

        function renderCalendar() {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                defaultDate: Date(),
                selectable: true,
                selectHelper: true,
                select: function(start, end) {
                    var title = prompt('Event Title:');
                    var eventData;
                    if (title) {
                        eventData = {
                            title: title,
                            start: start,
                            end: end
                        };
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
                    }
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
                },
                eventClick: function(event) {
                    $(this).popover({html:true,title:event.title,placement:'top',container:'body',content: 'vamo ver se vai agora'}).popover();
                },
                lang: currentLangCode,
                buttonIcons: false, // show the prev/next text
                weekNumbers: true,
                editable: false,
                eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                events: {
                    url: 'fullcalendar/demos/php/get-events.php',
                },
                loading: function(bool) {
                    $('#loading').toggle(bool);
                }
            });
        }

        renderCalendar();
    });
```

Comment: Você poderia colocar o código que utilizou até gora? Pelo que vi a documentação existem métodos para adicionar eventos ao calendário, mas acredito que pode ser adaptado com um ajax para adicionar ao banco.

Comment: Alterei a pergunta e coloquei o código JS atual do meu calendar, eu ja entendi como fazer para trazer os resultados do banco mas nao entendi como fazer pra inserir eles no banco

Comment: Esse eventClick que seria o responsável por gerar um novo evento?

Comment: Na verdade não este eventClick eh responsavel por aparecer um balaozinho com uma pequena descricao do evento em questao. o que faria adicionar um evento supostamente seria o evento select

Comment: que quando eu clico em algum dia aparece o prompt para eu digitar o title do event e ele colocar no no calendario mas como esta em js se eu atualizar a pagina ele vai sumir o evento, gostaria de saber se tem como eu inserir este evento no banco pra qdo atualizar a pagina o evento nao sumir

Comment: Pensei até em utilizar um modal bootstrap para fazer o formulario de inserção mas nao consegui encontrar uma maneira de enviar os dados para o banco

Comment: Jobson, sim há meios de fazer isso... você se lembra do ajax? `$.ajax({url: 'url-destino-da-requisicao', method: 'POST', dataType: 'json', data {codigo_evento: 1, descricao_evento: "bla bla bla"}}.done(function(data){console.log("parece que deu certo!")}))`.... Isso você pode adicionar junto ao seu evento de select ou uma função separada e chamar ela.

Comment: sim sim, entendo mas ai se eu utilizar o modal do bootstrap quando eu der o submit ele irá para a funcao ajax que esta dentro do select?

Comment: A minha intenção seria a seguinte eu pegar quando o usuario clicar em um dia aparecer um modal com um form para cadastro do evento, ai ele cadastrando o evento ficaria fixo independente de dar refresh na pagina ou nao.

Comment: Você pode fazer isso sim. Desde que tratado corretamente... caso seja um form dentro do modal, você intercepte o evento submit e não deixe dar o refresh da página. Ele não vai pegar o evento de dentro do select, não sei como ele funciona... você me disse que o select era o que cadastrada e alterava os eventos...

Comment: Ah sim agora entendi como fazer, eh só eu interceptar o submit, e dentro da funcao do submit eu colocar para enviar os dados via ajax para gravar no banco. Muito obrigado de verdade mesmo. Me ajudou bastante mesmo, estava empacado nisso :D